# How to always have the controller + action in the url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net mvc 4, I would like to always have in the url the controller name + the action name. Sometimes it works but for whatever reasons , when I start the application it just shows the name of the project + "/" even if I use a redirection to the default action.

there go my settings :

in routeConfig I have :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ProductionQueue", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

the redirection that I use :

```
return RedirectToAction( "Index", "ProductionQueue", null);
```

So the question is , is there a way to always have the controller + the action name in the url even if the optional parameter is null ? (at startup, when using a redirection etc.. )

Nb: the solution has to work in production

Comment: I think if you remove the `defaults` in your MapRouting, then you have to use the full path to every action. Therefore it must also displayed in the url

Comment: Try removing the `defaults` line.

Comment: it does'nt work when I remove the default line I get an error "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" an the url stays the same

Comment: @coldistric did you try to add [Route(“ProductionQueue/Index”)] onto your action method

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default case,

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    );
```

Although note you will then **not be able** to browse to the root of the site, you will have to specify a controller and action each time.

Comment: I did that, but now  how do I tell the app to start at a specific controller and action in production (for now the app still start with projectname + "/")

Comment: ... That is the defaults.. You cannot have both as far as I am aware...

Comment: The default route will show as /, so if you want to show the controller and action for this route - you will need to type the full route... You could add a redirect in IIS to redirect to this route if you wanted to do both?

Comment: How can I do that in IIS ?  Is there a file in Vs that I should modify ?

Comment: No I mean once you have deployed the web application... for within Visual Studio you can simply change the Start URL in the Project Properties (Right-Click Project and go Properties)